# Renaming wp_content problem

Tags: customization

I am setting wordpress in a custom way and having issues with renaming `wp-content`. Here are the details:

I am using Amazon AWS as my environment. The default web root is `/var/www/html/`. Within that directory, I have multiple projects, each having its own directory. So, my WordPress project is in `/var/www/html/project01`. So this leads to accessing the WordPress from the web browser via the following URL: `http://some-url.com/project01/index.php`.

The next step, I typically move WordPress files into a sub-directory. So, I moved all wordpress files into a directory named `red` inside `/var/www/html/project01` then copied `index.php` from that sub-directory back into the `project01` directory, and modified `index.php` as follows:

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/red/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

This resulted in the following directory structure:

```
/var/www/html
          |
          --------project01
                     |
                     -------- index.php /* modified as described above */
                     |
                     -------- red
                               |
                               -------- wp-config.php
                               |
                               -------- wp-content
                               |
                               -------- /* Other WordPress files and directories */
```

So far, everythig works great and without a problem. I can access both the front end and the admin area of the site.

The next step in my setup is to rename `wp-content` to something else as an added security measure. So, I renamed `wp-content` to `green`. So my directory structure now looks like this:

```
/var/www/html
          |
          --------project01
                     |
                     -------- index.php /* modified as described above */
                     |
                     -------- red
                               |
                               -------- wp-config.php
                               |
                               -------- green /* this is a renamed wp-content directory */
                               |
                               -------- /* Other WordPress files and directories */
```

To complete the directory rename, `wp-config.php` should be updated to reflect the changes made, so, I [followed the instructions described here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/renaming-wordpress-wp-content-folder/) and added the following to `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME', 'green');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);

define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_SITEURL . 'project01' . '/' . 'red' . '/' . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);
```

I added the above code just before the following line in `wp-config.php`:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

**IMPORTANT:** Please also note that the `WP_CONTENT_URL` parameter that I added in `wp-config.php` is set to include the changes in the directory strucuture described above.

Now, after doing so, if I go to `http://some-url.com/project01/index.php`, everything is fine and the site's front-end is displayed properly. **However, if I go to `http://some-url.com/project01/red/green/wp-admin` to login to the admin area, the page is redirected to `http://some-url.com/wp-login.php` as opposed to `http://some-url.com/project01/red/green/wp-login.php`, and I get a 404 error.**

So, my question is, what did I miss? What do I have to do to fix this problem? Is there a setup I have to do in `.htaccess` for example? Something else? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: renaming wp-content folder - http://www.kvcodes.com/2013/12/rename-wp-content-folder-and-uploads-wordpress/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just FYI:

After struggling for hours, I found the aswer. The line that was causing the problem is the following in my `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

It turned out my `WP_SITEURL` is not working correctly because I changed the directory structure as described in the question. So I modified `wp-config.php` and it now looks like this:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME', 'green');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);

define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/project01/');
define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME .  'red/');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_SITEURL . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);
```

Now, it works like a charm.